# Keras, multiclass classification of images with an added parameter for measure

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, classification, multiclass-classification

I am facing a classical problem of classification of images into 12 classes.
I am using a model based on Inception v3 to which I added 3 layers:

```
weights_url = "https://storage.googleapis.com/mledu-datasets/inception_v3_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels_notop.h5"
weights_file = "inception_v3.h5"
urllib.request.urlretrieve(weights_url, weights_file)

# Instantiate the model
pre_trained_model = InceptionV3(input_shape=(150, 150, 3),
                                include_top=False,
                                weights=None)

# load pre-trained weights
pre_trained_model.load_weights(weights_file)

# freeze the layers
for layer in pre_trained_model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False

# pre_trained_model.summary()

last_layer = pre_trained_model.get_layer('mixed7')
last_output = last_layer.output
x = layers.Conv2D(128,kernel_size=(3,3),activation='relu',padding='same')(last_output)
x = layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
x = layers.Dense(12, activation="softmax", name="classification")(x)

model = Model(pre_trained_model.input, x)
model.compile(optimizer='RMSprop',
               loss='categorical_crossentropy',
               metrics=['acc'])
model.summary()
```

I am reading the images from the file system using an ImageDataGenerator:

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255,
      zoom_range=0.2,
      horizontal_flip=True,
      fill_mode='nearest')
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(TRAINING_DIR,
                                                    batch_size=64,
                                                    class_mode='categorical',
                                                    target_size=(150, 150))
validation_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
validation_generator = validation_datagen.flow_from_directory(VALIDATION_DIR,
                                                              batch_size=64,
                                                              class_mode='categorical',
                                                              target_size=(150, 150))
```

I would like to train the classification based also on the measure, for which I have created a dictionary that associates an integer to each file name getting the data from a .csv

```
dict_measures = {}
for index, row in scales.iterrows():
  dict_measures[row['filename']] = row['measure']
```

The way I would tackle this issue is to zip the mixed data (Conv2d output, measure) just before the final Dense with softmax, then fit the model. The only issue would remain the creation of a generator for the measures in synch with the images, so I would set shuffle=False.
Does this make sense? Did any of you have to tackle a similar problem? What was your approach?